# Using Firestore document's auto-generated ID versus using a custom ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently deciding on my Firestore data structure.

I'll need a `products` collection, and the `products` items will live inside of it as documents.

Here are my **product's fields**:

- **uniqueKey:** string
- **description:** array of strings
- **images:** array of objects
- **price:** number

**QUESTION**

Should I use Firestore auto-generated ID's to be the `ID` of my documents, or is it better to use my `uniqueKey` (which I'll query for in many occasions) as the document ID? Is there a best option between the 2?

I imagine that if I use my `uniqueKey`, it will make my life easier when retrieving a single document, but I'll have to query for more than 1 product on many occasions too.

Using my `uniqueKey` as `ID`:

```
db.collection("products").doc("myUniqueKey").get();
```

Using my Firestore auto-generated `ID`:

```
db.collection("products").where("uniqueKey", "==", "myUniqueKey").get();
```

Is this enough of a reason to go with my `uniqueKey` instead of the auto-generated one? Is there a rule of thumb here? What's the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In terms of making queries from a client, using only the information you've given in the question, I don't see that there's much practical difference between a document get using its known ID, or a query on a field that is also unique.  Either way, an index is used on the server side, and it costs exactly 1 document read.  The document get() might be marginally faster, but it's not worthwhile to optimize like this (in my opinion).

When making decision about data modeling like this, it's more important to think about things like system behavior under load and security rules.

If you're reading and writing a lot of documents whose IDs have a sequential property, you could run into [hotspotting](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#hotspots) on those writes.  So, if you want to use your own ID, and you expect to be reading and writing them in that sequence under heavy load, you could have a problem.  If you don't anticipate this to be the situation, then it likely doesn't matter too much whose ID you use.

If you are going to use security rules to limit access to documents, and you use the contents of other documents to help with that, you'll need to be able to uniquely identify those documents in your rule.  You can't perform a query against a collection in rules, so you might need meaningful IDs that will give direct access when used by rules.  If your own IDs can be used easily this way in security rules, that might be more convenient overall.  If you're force to used Firestore's generated IDs, it might become inconvenient, difficult, or expensive to try to maintain a relationship between your IDs and Firestore's IDs.

In any event, the decision you're making is not just about which ID is "better" in a general sense, but which ID is better *for your specific, anticipated situation, under load, with security in mind*.

Comment: Thanks, Doug! I think that further down the road I'll know better how to reason about those choices. But that was really helpful!

Comment: @cbdeveloper Hey, I just wanna know how did you decide or more important, did any resource, blog post helped you to decide? :) Im just at the same decision to make

Comment: @lukas28277 Hey Lukas, for this kind of collection with possibly "infinite" items, like the `products` collection which you always be querying for some property anyway, I chose to go with the autoID. But for specific collections with finite number of items that I'll get the `doc` directly without querying, I give them a "dev-friendly" ID. Let's say I have a `siteData` collection with multiple docs each for one language. Each `doc` I would call `siteDataDoc_EN`, `siteDataDoc_FR`, etc. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) well Im about to make a db of users and will want to filter people by , lets say city, skills etc, therefore Im thinking of the best and most efficient way in the sense of number of reads necessary